# Java LWJGL Game

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm learning LWJGL and I am writing a simple game. But if I render the Level 200x200 I have 10-15 fps. I added a renderLimiter and with it I have 40-60 fps with Vsync. How I can faster the render? Here is a code (not 100%):

**Game.class:**

```
package main;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Canvas;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import Graphics.Render;
import Levels.level1;
import player.Player;

public class Game {

    DisplayMode dispMode = new DisplayMode(gameX, gameY);

    public static int gameX = 800;
    public static int gameY = 600;

    public static final float RenderDistance = 20.0f;
    public static final boolean Vsync = true;
    public static final boolean isApplet = false;

    private static Player player;

    int frames = 0;

    private level1 lvl1;

    public Game(){
        init();

    }
    public void init(){
        if(!isApplet) {
        try {
            initApplication();
            Render.init();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        player = new Player(45.0f, (float)dispMode.getWidth() / (float)dispMode.getHeight(), 0.5f, 300.0f);

        lvl1 = new level1();

        System.out.println("OpenGL version : "+ GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));

        gameLoop();
    }
    public void start(){

    }
    public void stop(){

    }
    public void destroy(){

    }
    public void initApplication() throws LWJGLException{
        Display.setDisplayMode(dispMode);

        Display.setVSyncEnabled(Vsync);
        Display.setFullscreen(true);
        Display.create();

        initGl();
    }   
    public void initGl(){
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float)dispMode.getWidth() / (float)dispMode.getHeight(), 2f, RenderDistance*2-10);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);

        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); 
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    }
    public void cleanUp(){
        Display.destroy();
    }
    public void gameLoop(){

        double unprocessedSeconds = 0;
        long previousTime = System.nanoTime();
        double secondsPerTick = 1 / 60.0;
        int tickCount = 0;
        boolean ticked = false;

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glLoadIdentity();

            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            long passedTime = currentTime - previousTime;

            previousTime = currentTime;
            unprocessedSeconds += passedTime / 1000000000.0;

            while(unprocessedSeconds > secondsPerTick){
                tick();
                unprocessedSeconds -= secondsPerTick;
                ticked = true;
                tickCount++;
                if(tickCount % 60 == 0){
                    System.out.println("FPS: "+frames);
                    System.out.println("----------");
                    System.out.println("PlayerX: "+player.getX());
                    System.out.println("PlayerY: "+player.getY());
                    System.out.println("PlayerZ: "+player.getZ());
                    previousTime += 1000;
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }
            if(ticked){
                tick();
                frames++;
            }       
            render();
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                cleanUp();
            }
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(100);
        }
        cleanUp();
    }
    public void tick(){
        player.tick(lvl1);
    }
    public static boolean inRenderRange(int x, int y, int z){
        if(x - RenderDistance > player.getX()/2 || y - RenderDistance > player.getY()/2 || z - RenderDistance > player.getZ()/2){
            return false;
        }else{
            if(x + RenderDistance < player.getX()/2 || y + RenderDistance < player.getY()/2 || z + RenderDistance < player.getZ()/2){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void render(){   
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        player.tick(lvl1);

        lvl1.render();
        /*for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                //Render.drawCube(i*2, 1, j*2, 0, Textures.floor);
                new Wall(new Vector3f(i*2, 0, j*2));
            }
        }*/
        Render.drawSphere(1, 1, 1, 3);
        Render.drawCube(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getZ()-5, 30);

        /*for(int i = 0; i <200; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 200; j++){
                Render.drawCube(i, 0, j, new Vector3f(.5f, .3f, 0f));
            }
        }*/
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Game();
    }
}
```

**Render.class:**

```
    import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.Sphere;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class Render {

    private static FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 4 * 6);

    public Render(){
    }
    public static void init(){
        vertices.put(new float[] {
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

                -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,

                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

                1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

                -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f}); 
    }
    public static void drawTile(float x, float y, float z, float angle, float r, float g, float b){
        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            glRotatef(angle, 8, 1, 0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
                glColor3f(r, g, b);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
            }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawTile(float x, float y, float z, float angle, Texture texture){
        texture.bind();

        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            glRotatef(angle, 8, 1, 0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
                glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
                glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
                glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
                texture.release();
            }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawTile(float x, float y, float z, float angle){
        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            glRotatef(angle, 8, 1, 0);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
                glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
            }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawLine(float x, float y, float z, float xx, float yy, float zz){
        glPushMatrix();{
            glBegin(GL_LINE);{
                glVertex3f(x,y,z);
                glVertex3f(xx,yy,zz);
            }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float angle, Texture texture){
        texture.bind();

        glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);
        glRotatef(angle,8,1,0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{

        //FrontFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);

        //BackFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);

        //BottomFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);

        //TopFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);

        //LeftFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);

        //Right Face
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);


        texture.release();
        }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }

    public static void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, Vector3f color){
         glTranslatef(x, y, z);

         glColor3f(color.x, color.y, color.z);

         glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         vertices.rewind();
         glVertexPointer(3, 0, vertices);

         glPushMatrix();{
             glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
         }glPopMatrix();

         glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         glColor3f(1,1,1);
    }
    public static void drawTriangle(float x, float y, float z){
        FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
        cBuffer.put(1).put(0).put(0);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(1).put(0);
        cBuffer.put(0).put(0).put(1);
        cBuffer.flip();

      FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
      vBuffer.put(-0.5f).put(-0.5f).put(0.0f);
      vBuffer.put(+0.5f).put(-0.5f).put(0.0f);
      vBuffer.put(+0.5f).put(+0.5f).put(0.0f);
      vBuffer.flip();

      glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

      glColorPointer(3, /* stride */3 << 2, cBuffer);
      glVertexPointer(3, /* stride */3 << 2, vBuffer);
      glPushMatrix();
      glTranslatef(x, y, z);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, /* elements */3);
      glPopMatrix();
      glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
      glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
    }
    public static void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float size,float angle, Texture texture){
        texture.bind();

        float scale = size / 8f;

        glPushMatrix();{
        glTranslatef(x,y,z);
        glRotatef(angle,8,1,0);
        glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);{
        //FrontFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);

        //BackFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);

        //BottomFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);

        //TopFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);

        //LeftFace
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);

        //Right Face
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(1,1,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(-1,1,1);


        texture.release();
        }glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawCube(float x, float y, float z, float angle){

        glPushMatrix();{

            glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            glRotatef(angle,8,1,0);

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);{

                glColor3f(1f,0f,0f);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,1);

                glColor3f(0f,1f,0f);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);

                glColor3f(0f,0f,1f);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);

                glColor3f(0.5f,1f,0f);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,-1);

                glColor3f(0f,0.5f,1f);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);

                glColor3f(1f,0.5f,1f);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
                glVertex3f(1,1,1);
                glVertex3f(-1,1,1);

                glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
            }
            glEnd();
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
    public static void drawSphere(float x, float y, float z, float size){
        glPushMatrix();{
            glTranslatef(x, y, z);
            Sphere s = new Sphere();
            s.draw(size, 16, 16);
        }glPopMatrix();
    }
```

**Object.class:**

```
    import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

public abstract class Object {
    public Vector3f cords;

    Texture texture;

    String name;

    public Object(float x, float y, float z){
        cords = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
        setUp();
        render();
    }
    public Object(Vector3f cords){
        this.cords = cords;
        render();
    }
    public Object(float x, float y, float z, Texture texture){
        this.texture = texture;
        render();
    }
    public Object(Vector3f cords, Texture texture){
        this.cords = cords;
        this.texture = texture;
        render();
    }
    public Vector3f getCoordinates(){
        return cords;
    }
    public Texture getTexture(){
        if(texture != null){
            return texture;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setTexture(Texture texture){
        this.texture = texture;
    }
    public void setCoords(Vector3f cords){
        this.cords = cords;
    }
    public float getX(){
        return cords.x;
    }
    public float getY(){
        return cords.y;
    }
    public float getZ(){
        return cords.z;
    }
    public abstract void render();
    public abstract void setUp();

}
```

**Floor.class:**

```
    import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

import Graphics.Render;
import Graphics.Textures;
import main.Object;

public class Floor extends Object{

    public Floor(Vector3f cords) {
        super(cords);
        setTexture(Textures.floor);
        setName("FLOOR");
    }
    public void render(){
        //Render.drawTile(cords.x, cords.y - 0.01f, cords.z, 0, Textures.floor);
        Render.drawCube(cords.x, cords.y, cords.z, 0, Textures.floor);
    }
    public void setUp() {
    }
}
```

Wall.class is really simple.

If you want more code tell me. And sorry for my english :(.

Comment: Basically, by using VBO's. Google it and follow a tutorial. They give great performance improvement on the rendering side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you can do is use different rendering techniques, a lot of your methods in your renderer class use what is called Immediate Mode rendering. Try learning how to use Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO's) or Display Lists. They are much faster and will drastically increase your games average FPS. :)